# How Firefox process without admin rights is able to update its own executable file?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, security

I'm using Windows 7 and as usually I have different user accounts for different programs for browsing internet. It was good practice since Win2000, almost no malware is able to work under restricted user account. I have several batch files with related `runas <user> <commandline>` commands inside.

Today I saw regular naggy popup in Firefox window about available update. Firefox process was ran under user named "inet", member of group Users, SID S-1-5-32-545. This user is allowed only to change files inside its own profile directory. I clicked on "Update" and after Firefox restart, the executable file at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` has new, fresh file creation timestamp.

I know about the Windows service named MozillaMaintenance, but it was not running before update. When I tried to start it manually, I got error with code 7023 "Incorrect Function". This service have SD

```
D:
(A;;CCLCSWRPWPLORC;;;IU)
(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)
(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)
(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)
S:
(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

(I got it from `sc sdshow MozillaMaintenance`).

It looks like interactive users (IU) are able to start this service, Firefox doing this maybe with some parameter unknown to me.

My question is: how on Earth is it possible to create a kind of backdoors for updating system-wide executable files from an unprivileged user account and how to restrict it without breaking the whole autoupdate system of Firefox?

This question is a bit academical, because nowadays no-one seems to be interested in using users and groups, they are putting containers into VMs within other containers. But maybe someone still have an urge to use OS native security.

Comment: You don’t restrict it. You simply disable the automatic update function. Firefox and Chromium had develop service accounts (where appropriate) and services due to the security changes within Windows (i.e UAC)

Comment: in the end, you needed admin to install the browser initially for a reason. you choose to install and trust that software to do what it does, which in this case is to install a service that can update the software for you without additional admin checks. its not like just any software can act as admin; an admin had to trust it for the initial installation.

Comment: @Ramhound, did you noticed this sentence: 
------
ran under user named "inet", member of group Users, SID S-1-5-32-545"
------

Can you tell me, how on Earth the casual users was allowed to change any files inside Program Files? I see no special permissions on Firefox folder. I see no "servce accounts". And I don't want to see any "service account" which allows casual user to change executable files shared for the whole machine.

Answer (score 0):

To disable updates for a particular user profile with the Firefox browser, via the `prefs.js` file, perform the following:

> Close Firefox.
>
> Navigate to the following location based on your operating system.
>
> - Windows XP/Vista/7/8/10 – `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox`
> - Unix/Linux – `~/.mozilla/`
> - Mac OS X – `~/Library/Mozilla/` or `~/Library/Application Support/`
>
> Open the “Profiles” folder.
>
> Open the folder that represents the profile you would like to edit.
> The name of the folder will vary. It is usually a bunch of characters,
> followed by “.default”.
>
> Open the `prefs.js` file with a text editor like Notepad.
>
> Look for a line that contains `app.update.enabled`. If it doesn’t
> exist, add a line for it in the file and set it as desired using these
> examples:
>
> - `user_pref("app.update.enabled", true);` = Automatic updates enabled
> - `user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);` = Automatic updates disabled

CREDIT: https://www.technipages.com/enable-disable-automatic-updates-in-firefox

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: I checked it and it says user_pref("app.update.enabled", false); but I got a message that I had to restart Firefox because it was doing a update on the background... Weird...